# Is std::move necessary when storing an expensive object in a pair?

Tags: c++, move, move-semantics, std-pair

Consider the following snippet from a function:

```
...
std::string someStdString;
...
// someStdString is filled here.
...
StringWrapper wrapper {std::move(someStdString)}; // First std::move usage.
return std::pair<bool, StringWrapper> {true, std::move(wrapper)}; // Second usage.
```

The `StringWrapper` class implements all four copy and move constructors and assignment operators and its constructor is explicit.

Are both the first and second usages of `std::move` justified, or are one or both of them not necessary?

Comment: Why do it in 2 steps?

Comment: For readability, for example. So yes, the temporaries are named.

Comment: You can replace those 2 lines with `return {true, std::move(someStdString)};`, and yes, that one `std::move` is required.

Comment: The StringWrapper constructor is explicit, and besides the wrapper itself could be used before the return (this is a simplified snippet). So in that case both moves are necessary?

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for the tip on eliminating the type declaration in return.

Comment: Yep, given all those constraints, both `std::move`s are required, and the only improvement would be not mentioning `std::pair` in the return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both of the `std::move`s are needed to ensure the move constructor gets invoked. The simple rule of thumb is "If it has a name, it is an lvalue." The only exception is when you are returning an automatic duration object which is about to go out of scope - this object is treated as an xvalue and is preferentially binds to the move constructor.

Comment: I wonder what are the reasons for not treating the wrapper object from the snippet as an about-to-expire one, even though it is not directly returned, but via the pair. Optimizer implementation complexity, or perhaps something more substantial?

Comment: @SeaCoastofTibet: try specifying the rules for that in an unambiguous and safe way. The current rules work quite well for old and new code alike.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::pair<bool, StringWrapper> foo() {
  std::string someStdString;
  // ... someStdString is filled here. ...
  return {true, std::move(someStdString)};
}
```

I see little reason to include most of your code, let alone two `move`s.

A `std::make_pair` if you want to be explicit about returning a pair, or are in a half compliant compiler.

As written above, `StringWrapper` is implicitly creatable from `std::string`, so the implicit creation should not be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is at efficient as it gets.

```
return std::make_pair(true, StringWrapper { std::move(someStdString });
```

Total number of moves: 1

Why? Because of copy elision of temporaries and Return Value Optimisaton.

It's also very readable.

Comment: Next step, move generation of someStdString to a separate method `std::string getSomeStdString();` and then you don't need any explicit moves at all: `make_pair(true, StringWrapper { getSomeStdString() });`